# Jade paragraph nesting

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, markup

How to place more than 1 nested element in paragraph
I have

```
    p
      label Item image
      .input-group
         input#addItemFile.form-control(type='file')
         input.form-control(type='text', readonly='')
         span.input-group-addon.btn.btn-default.btn-file.btn-primary Browse
```

And expect

```
<input class="form-control" id="addItemFile" type="file">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="">
    <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file btn-primary">Browse</span>
```

But i get

```
<p>
<label>Item image</label>
</p>
<div class="input-group"><input class="form-control" id="addItemFile" type="file">
<input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="">
<span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file btn-primary">Browse</span>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: That was my stupid to wrap form items in <p> tag, better using .form-group class for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
 p  label Item image
      .input-group
         input#addItemFile.form-control(type='file')
         input.form-control(type='text', readonly='')
         span(class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file btn-primary") Browse
```

The above code nests for me fine. Output in Firefox:

```
<p> label Item image<div class="input-group"><input id="addItemFile" type="file" class="form-control"><input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file btn-primary">Browse</span></div></p>
```

Comment: http://aramboyajyan.github.io/online-jade-template-editor/ says "[jade] unexpected token "indent"" when I try that.

Comment: Hhhmmmm, that's probably an issue with the way I've reproduced it. Unfortunately JSFiddle isn't playing ball for me at the moment which is making things difficult, but I'll have another go and edit with the working code as the solution concept is correct...

Comment: Fixed now. Working fine on my server with correct indentation (gave up with JSFiddle).

Comment: It has the same problem the original code does. It tries to put a `<div>` inside the paragraph, which isn't allowed.

Comment: I can understand if the specifications do not allow it, but the above code does nest a div inside the `<p>` element when the Jade is transpiled to HTML.

Comment: It doesn't. It puts a div start tag before a p end tag, that isn't the same thing. The browser then ends the p because it reached a div start tag and ignores the p end tag. That's why the code in the question doesn't work.

Comment: The `div` element is nested inside the `p` element within the HTML. Though when I look again at the original question it appears the asker expected to see no `<p>` or `</p>` tag at all. So perhaps the correct answer would be just to remove the `p` from the original code entirely... yet it appeared to me as if the asker has a reason to put it there...

Comment: "The div element is nested inside the p element within the HTML" — It isn't. The div start tag, by the rules of HTML, ends the paragraph. The `</p>` is then just invalid.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting on a conceptual level. Soooo, according to the rules of HTML (1.0 to 5?) the start of a paragraph tag automatically ends a div element even if the `</div>` tag is not explicitly used? Is this an absolute rule for all browsers and HTML versions or is it contextual?

Comment: Other way around. The end tag for a paragraph is optional. The start tag for any element that is not allowed inside a paragraph (including div) will implicitly end the paragraph. This is true of all versions of HTML (except XHTML) and I'm not aware of any browser that doesn't support it.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the other way around. Dyslexic. Interesting to note the XHTML exception.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will generate markup with the div inside the paragraph. The problem is that **HTML forbids divs from appearing there** so the browser will implicitly end the paragraph before the div and then discard the end tag for the paragraph.

You need to use an element that is allowed inside a paragraph instead.

e.g. `span.input-group`